# String comparison two strings not the same

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, html, comparison

When I try to run my code, I output the content inside the li elements and compare it with the new data from the api. (I know that the new data is the same data from before). And yet my comparison of strings returns false. I used alert on each strings and I see that they are the same string. here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Boot Camp</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="refreshview.js"></script>
<script src="loadview.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
loadview();
</script>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
<div data-role="header"> 
<h1>New DVD Releases</h1> 
</div> 
<div data-role="content" >
<ul data-role="listview" id="datalist"></ul>
</div>
</body></html>
```

I call loadview to put li elemts in my ul

```
function loadview() {
$.ajax({
url:'http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/lists/dvds/new_releases.json?    page_limit=16&page=1&country=us&apikey=k4uaze4937mw3hf82upstxqw',
type:'GET',
dataType:'jsonp',
success:function(data){
    var movies = data.movies;
    $.each(movies, function() {
    $('#datalist').append('<li><a><img src='+this.posters.thumbnail+' class="ui-li-thumb"><h3 class="ui-li-heading">'+this.title+'</h3><p class="ui-li-desc">DVD Date: '+this.release_dates.dvd+'</p></a></li>');    
    //get data from ul
    });
    $('#datalist').listview('refresh'); 
    refreshview();//every 30 seconds
},

error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert('request failed :'+xhr);
                    alert('request failed :'+textStatus);
    alert('request failed :'+errorThrown);
}
}); 
};
```

and after the code loads i call refreshview to run the same api query and compare the values in li wit the elememts I get online ( should be the same).

```
function refreshview() {
$.ajax({
url:'http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/lists/dvds/new_releases.json?page_limit=16&page=1&country=us&apikey=k4uaze4937mw3hf82upstxqw',
type:'GET',
dataType:'jsonp',
success:function(data){
    var movies = data.movies;
    var lis = new Array();
    var i=0;

    $("#datalist").children("li").each(function()
    {
     lis.push($(this).text());
    });

    $.each(movies, function() {
        alert (this.title+"DVD Date: "+this.release_dates.dvd+"\n"+lis[i]);
        alert ($.trim(this.title+"DVD Date: "+this.release_dates.dvd)==$.trim(lis[i]));
        if (($.trim(this.title+"DVD Date: "+this.release_dates.dvd))==$.trim(lis[i]))
            {
             alert ("hi"+i);//add the new item to listofchanges
             i++;
            }


    });
},

error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert('request failed :'+xhr);
                    alert('request failed :'+textStatus);
    alert('request failed :'+errorThrown);
}
}); 
};
```

My alerts show that the 2 strings are always the same. but the comparisons "==" always return false. I even tried using trim but it only fixed the first one.

Why is == returning false? Is there an illegal character in there? And how do I convert these 2 strings to the same "format"

Comment: did you check whether the cases are name... also can you share the strings that are compared

Comment: As a sidenote, $.each has an index as a parameter, no need to create your own ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, i is only being incremented if they are the same so the first element in the lis array needs to match the first element in the refreshed movies array. Are they the same movie listing? Or did the refresh bring them back in a different order? In other words, is The Godfather in position 0 in loadview but in position 5 in refreshview?